# In the VM I create a NIC, configed the IP address, but can not connect to the internet

Tags: networking, virtual-machines

（Ignore I did not post code, because in the VMware I can not copy any code from remote server）

I have created a VMnet6, its IP section is `45.117.42.0`, my host machine ip is `45.117.42.129`. the gateway is `45.117.42.2`.

[image]

And in the VM(cc-controller1, CentOS7.2), I config the IP address here:

[image]

And I restarted the network:

```
systemctl restart network
```

I can not ping the outer network and the gateway still, why?

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

Before, I have config three VM's IP with the `45.117.42.120`,`45.117.42.121`,`45.117.42.122`, and the BOOTPROTO is static too.

But in there I have closed them, I am not sure if this will affected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At last, I find the order of the NIC is wrong, so I adjusted them to the right order:

[image]

Before I gets wrong order of the VMnet2 and VMnet6.